# Using a Variable to change .Location of an object in VB

Tags: vb.net

Im wanting the pic1's location to change based off of the current x value of picHeli as it moves along.

```
Dim z As Integer = 0
Controls.Add(pic2)
pic1.Location((z), (55))
```

Comment: OK, what's your question?

Comment: You should read MSDN website to find an answer to your question! The answer is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx)!

Answer (score 1):

To change a location you need to reset the property with a new point.

```
pic1.Location = New Point(z, 55)
```